# fo:inline-elements create unwanted whitespace

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace, xsl-fo

From an XML file (originally a Word file) I create a PDF with XSLT and XSLFO. Bold font is to be adopted. This works, but the PDF contains unwanted spaces in the bold words (see "unwanted result"). The reason is that `fo:inline` creates spaces within `fo:block` (Word incomprehensibly splits some words into several `w:t` elements). The renderer is FOP.

I have no idea how to turn it off that the white space is generated. I have already tried some white space settings, like `xsl:strip-space elements` and `white-space-collapse`, but without success.

Why does the stylesheet create white space between `fo:inline` and how can I fix this?

**Unwanted Result**

from the PDF: "*... weil **Fi l mmaterial** in der ...*"

**Wanted Result**

It should be: "*... weil **Filmmaterial** in der ...*"

**SOURCE**, shortened by some elements (which are not crucial) for the sake of clarity

```
    <div class="listlevel-1">
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>... weil </w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Fi</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>l</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>mmaterial</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:t> in der digitalen ...</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </div>
```

**XSLT-Stylesheet**, shortened by some elements (which are not crucial) for the sake of clarity

2 XSLT stylesheets intertwine during the transformation. The problem occurs within lists. One stylesheet transforms lists (1), the second transforms all text elements (w:t elements) that are bold, italic or underlined.

1)

```
    <xsl:template match="//div[@class = 'listlevel-1']/w:p">
        <fo:list-item xsl:use-attribute-sets="listitem">
            <fo:list-item-label xsl:use-attribute-sets="itemlabel">
                <fo:block>•</fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body xsl:use-attribute-sets="itembody">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>
```

2. 

Several `xsl:choose` branches are used to query several conditions; conditions 2 and 3 are not listed here because of their length, but they are structured exactly like condition 1.

```
    <xsl:template match="//w:t">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="../w:rPr/w:b">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="../w:rPr/w:u">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="../w:rPr/w:i">
                                <fo:inline>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="text-decoration">underline</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="font-style">italic</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                </fo:inline>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <fo:inline>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="text-decoration">underline</xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                </fo:inline>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
    
    ...
    
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

**FO-File**, what the code looks like in the FO file:

```
      <fo:block>... weil 
       <fo:inline font-weight="bold">Fi</fo:inline>
       <fo:inline font-weight="bold">l</fo:inline>
       <fo:inline font-weight="bold">mmaterial</fo:inline> in ...
      </fo:block>
```

Comment: Maybe you use:   <xsl:output  indent="yes" />. If so, change that to   <xsl:output  indent="no" />
And if your source is already indented, use:   <xsl:strip-space elements="w:r"/>

Comment: Bingo! `output indent="no"` did it. So simple and yet overlooked. Thanks! If you post that as a reply, I can choose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you used: `<xsl:output indent="yes" />`.

If so, change that to `<xsl:output indent="no" />`

And if your source is already indented, use: `<xsl:strip-space elements="w:r"/>`